# Using recursion to reverse an integer without trailing 0's in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, integer

I am stuck on how to omit trailing zeros, on a recursive call to reverse an integer. If you could just guide me to the right path I'd appreciate it. I am stuck and do not know how to do it. I have came this far, but am struggling to complete it. Thanks.

```
int main() {
    int numToReverse;

    cout << "Please enter in a number: " << endl;
    cin >> numToReverse;

    cout << reverseIntRecursion(numToReverse) << endl;

}


int reverseIntRecursion(int n) {
    if (n < 10)  //Base Case
        return n;
    else
        cout << n % 10; // Prints out the last number
        return reverseIntRecursion(n / 10); // General Case, Recursive Function
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]. Also please provide data that gives wrong output and expected one.

Comment: Why your recursive function returns `int` and it suppose to return?

Comment: Your `reverseIntRecursion` doesn't reverse an `int`. It just prints all the digits in the reverse order.

Comment: Your function always returns the leftmost digit of the number. Don't mix computation and output. Make either a function that prints the digits in reverse *or*  a function that returns a reversed integer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe easiest way is parse int to string (array of chars) and print as array?

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code that works just fine as long as you enter true for the second parameter:

```
int ReverseIntRecursion(int, bool);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::cout << ReverseIntRecursion(30400, true);
    std::cout << std::endl;


    return 0;
}

int ReverseIntRecursion(int N, bool FirstIter)
{
    if (N < 10)
        return N;
    else if (N % 10 == 0 && FirstIter)
        return ReverseIntRecursion(N/10, true);
    else
        std::cout << (N % 10);
    return ReverseIntRecursion(N/10, false);
}
// prints 403
```

Comment: OP wants to omit trailing zeros, not all of them

Answer (score -1):

Your function isn't reversing an integer. It just prints digits in a reverse order.

This is why you are getting your trailing zeros problem. If you wrote a function which actually reversed the integer - your problem would disappear.

For example:

```
// Helper function for reversing an integer.
int reverseIntRecursionBase(int n, int& base) {
    if (n < 10) // trivial case. If n consists of a single digit - reversed n is equal to n.
        {
        return n;
        }

    int result = reverseIntRecursionBase (n/10, base); // recurse until you hit a trivial case.
    /*
       The leftmost digits in the original number should be the
       rightmost digits in the reversed number.
       This code will be first executed, after trivial case has been hit:
       e.g. given number 1234, this line will be first reached when n = 12; result = 1.
    */
    base *= 10;
    result = (n % 10)*base + result;
    return result;
}

int reverseIntRecursion(int n) {
    int base = 1;
    return reverseIntRecursionBase (n, base);
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/dCTO3s).

Comment: May the downvoter explain the reason for a downvote?